# Display recurring column values once with second column unchanged

Tags: sql, database

So what I want to do is to display is one column "Customer Name" that only displays the customer's name once and a second column "Product Purchased" that displays all the products purchased by the customer. So say, Bob buys a car, a phone, and a watch; what I what to display is

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''
'Customer  'Product   '
'Name      'Purchased '
'''''''''''''''''''''''
'Bob       'Car       '
'          'Phone     '
'          'Watch     '
'''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Right now the statement that I have is

```sql
SELECT 
    Customers.Name AS 'Customer Name',
    Items.ItemName AS 'Product'
FROM
    Orders
        INNER JOIN
    Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN
    Items ON Orders.ItemID = Items.ItemID;
```

And it displays everything name from the Customer table and their corresponding products purchased as it should but it duplicates the customer's name.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: For what it's worth, this kind of report formatting is often best when done in your application program rather than the dbms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to determine whether each row is the first order for that customer or not:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Orders o2
        WHERE o2.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID AND o2.OrderID < Orders.OrderID
    ) THEN Customers.Name ELSE '' END AS 'Customer Name',
    Items.ItemName AS 'Product'
FROM
    Orders
        INNER JOIN
    Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN
    Items ON Orders.ItemID = Items.ItemID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID, Orders.OrderID ASC;
```

Comment: @7g3p . . . In addition to being unnecessarily cumbersome, I don't think this does what you want if the lowest order id for a customer has multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

You would not use a subquery for this.  Normally, this type of transformation is done in the application layer.  But if you do it in the database, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.CustomerId ORDER BY o.OrderId, i.ItemName)
             THEN c.Name
        END) as Customer_Name,
       i.ItemName AS Product
FROM Orders o JOIN
     Customers c
     ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID JOIN
     Items i
     ON o.ItemID = i.ItemID
ORDER BY c.CustomerID, o.OrderID ASC, i.itemName;
```

Note that this uses table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.